# Create Hive table from parquet files and load the data

Tags: apache-spark, hive, schema, external, parquet

I am finding it difficult to load parquet files into hive tables. I am working on Amazon EMR cluster and spark for Data processing. But i need to read the output parquet files to validate my transformations. i have the parquet files with following schema:

```
root
 |-- ATTR_YEAR: long (nullable = true)
 |-- afil: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |-- clm: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- amb: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- L: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- cdTransRsn: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- dist: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |-- T: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |-- content: double (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- dscStrchPurp: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- amt: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- L: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- T: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- content: double (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- amtTotChrg: double (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- cdAccState: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- cdCause: string (nullable = true)
```

how can i create hive external table using this type of schema and load the parquet files into that hive table for analysis?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`Catalog.createExternalTable`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.sql.catalog.Catalog@createExternalTable(tableName:String,source:String,schema:org.apache.spark.sql.types.StructType,options:Map[String,String]):org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame) (Spark before 2.2) or [`Catalog.createTable`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.sql.catalog.Catalog@createTable(tableName:String,source:String,schema:org.apache.spark.sql.types.StructType,options:java.util.Map[String,String]):org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame) (Spark 2.2 and later).

`Catalog` instance can be accessed using `SparkSession`:

```
val spark: SparkSession
spark.catalog.createTable(...)
```

Session should be initialized with Hive support enabled.

Comment: I am not sure what put inside the createTable(...here...). i only have the parquet files and dont have the schema/metadata files stored separately. i can create a dataframe with these parquet files and do printSchema() which i have pasted in my question. Now how to createTable ? with this type of nested schema in hive is my question?